# Background transparente

Tags: html, css

Sou leigo em css, e  não sei porque não está ficando transparente uma determinada área que marquei. Coloquei no jsfiddle

[codigo](https://jsfiddle.net/PH7Jack/gukLf5ds/8/)

Quando coloco a parte em vermelho como transparente ela some. Mas qualquer outra cor funciona. 
OBS: Colocar branco vai parecer que está transparente, mas não é isso que quero fazer.

edit1: Tudo que quero fazer é deixar a área vermelha como transparente sem pegar a cor azul, mas o fundo atrás do azul

Comment: O que você quer fazer exatamente?

Comment: Juro que não consegui entender sua questão. Mas tem algo haver com espaço de cores RGBA, onde R é um inteiro entre 0 e 255 indicando a intensidade do Vermelho, onde G é um inteiro entre 0 e 255 indicando a intensidade do Verde, onde B é um inteiro entre 0 e 255 indicando a intensidade do Azul e finalmente  A que é um inteiro entre 0 e 255 indicando a intensidade da transparência onde 0 é totalmente transparente e 255 é uma coro opaca.

Comment: Tudo que quero fazer é deixar a área vermelha como transparente sem pegar a cor azul, mas o fundo atrás do azul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se é isso que você está procurando, mas eu apliquei no quadrado(classe `base`) o atributo CSS `mix-blend-mode` com o valor `hard-light`.

A propriedade [`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) descreve como um elemento de conteúdo deve ser mesclado com os elementos abaixo dele no background, no caso background xadrez.

O valor `hard-light` é a combinação dos filtros de mistura Screen e Multiply o que torna os objetos cinza(classe `content`) transparentes.

```css
.body{
 background-color: black;
 width: 400px;
 height: 300px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #808080 25%, transparent 25%), linear-gradient(-45deg, #808080 25%, transparent 25%), linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, #808080 75%), linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 75%, #808080 75%);
        background-size: 20px 20px;
        background-position: 0 0, 0 10px, 10px -10px, -10px 0px;
}

.base {
 position: relative;
 left: 10px;
 top: 0px;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 border: solid 1px black;
 background-color: blue;
 mix-blend-mode: hard-light;
}

.content {
    position:absolute;
    background-color: gray;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    top:-100px;
    border-radius:100%; 
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
    
 <div class="base">      
        <div class="content"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exatamente isso, eu desconhecia essa propriedade, tentei e não funcionava, muito obrigado man

Comment: Seria possível usar outras cores também pra obter o mesmo resultado? Ao invés de Cinza, azul, vermelho...

Comment: Com `hard-light` só o cinza. Isso porque o `mix-blend-mode` instrui sistematicamente ao renderizador a maneira como operar as componentes de pixel e o cinza(nesse caso) funciona como uma mascara(chromakey). Para operar com outras cores RGB ou RGBA use outros valores `mix-blend-mode`.

Comment: Cada cor no espaço RGB possui três componente R(vermelho), G(verde) e B(azul) que variam, inclusive, entre 0 e 255 portanto 256 variações sendo que o número 127 é o centro.O blend mode `hard-light` é um operador que gera transparência no ponto médio de cada canal rgb(127, 127, 127) o cinza. Para cada canal podemos criar um ajuste independente de transparência e para diferentes que 127(maiores ou menores) diminui um grau de transparência, valores maiores que 127 o canal do background é exibido multiplicado por 2 e menores que 127 o canal é dividido por 2. Ex:rgb(255, 127, 127) no lugar de gray.

Comment: Usando esse vermelho fica 80% transparente, minha outra dúvida é, como faz ignorar isso em um elemento x? Se você tiver tutoriais dessas coisas, gostaria de ver